# iOS when I click on an Associated Domain within my own app, safari is launched instead

Tags: ios, associated-domains

I have an associated domain. If I click on a link to that domain from anywhere outside my app, the app is launched.

If I click on it inside my app, safari is launched instead.

Why is this happening? Can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623073-application?language=objc)

*Intercept links from openURL and links from other components like UITextView - present custom alert and on the alert delegate either cancel or redirect to the link*